# How do I get the ID from several URLs in a textarea?

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a small bot for getting every id from several URLs in a textarea

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <?php
 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 

    $name = trim($_POST['textarea']);
     $url =nl2br( $name);

$parts = explode('/', $url);
preg_match("/([0-9]+)\/?/", $url, $output_array);
$id =$output_array[1];
echo $id ;


}
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<textarea name="textarea" placeholder="Enter the text..."></textarea>
     <?php 
 ?> 
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Jbed Lien"><br>
</form>

 </body>
</html>
```

Sample URLs:

sitename/1.html

sitename/2.html

sitename/3.html

sitename/4.html

RESULT :
ID :1
ID ;2
ID :3

Comment: What do you mean by the ID of a URL?

Comment: https://www.avoirfilm.com/21-Beats-cUkmF.html like this url the id is the first number 21 - https://www.avoirfilm.com/21-Beats-cUkmF.html - https://www.avoirfilm.com/22-Beats-cUkmF.html - https://www.avoirfilm.com/23-Beats-cUkmF.html

Comment: and im loking to get all id if i pot 5 or mor url lik this

Comment: So you just want the number?

Comment: yes but get all number if i put 5 url or more

Answer (score 0):

Change the function you are using for string search, from `preg_match` to `preg_match_all`.

```php
// Use this code:
preg_match_all("/([0-9]+)\/?/", $url, $output_array);

// Instead of using this:
preg_match("/([0-9]+)\/?/", $url, $output_array);
```

I would also suggest you to change your REGEX to the following: `/\/([0-9]+)\./`, but it might need change if your URLs structures change.